# How data filling on grid can be Aborted in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, database, telerik, radgrid, abort

When there are lots of data to display on grid from database then the loading time might become an issue. For sometimes user might want to ABORT the data filling. I am using RadGrid and want to handle this scenario using a button. When the button is pressed the data filling will be aborted.I am using Ajax for filling the data into the grid. Can you please suggest me something to achieve this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

If you find a way to abort a running process or method in ASP, please share it with us and use it to abort the OnNeedDataSource handler. I am not aware of a way to do this, however.

If you initiate another AJAX request from the same page before the first one has returned to the browser, the second one will cancel the first (this is the behavior of the MS AJAX framework), but this will not cancel the server operation. If this is enough for your, just start a timer (see the setTimeout() function) and initiate a postback (see the __doPostBack() function).